# Time Series prediction using R

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, r, time-series

I have a dataset which contains data related to the exchange rate in a certain time period(2013-2015). The dataset has a column date with YYYY/MM/DD format and USD/EUR which contains the exchange rate.
I would like to know what are the preprocessing steps need to follow and how to predict the values using neuralnet package and compare with test data?